# Zabbix monitoring event log

Tags: windows-event-log, zabbix

i want monitoring event log event id:5002,5004,5007. i have create item: [Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shBRO.png)
when i create trigger is error:Incorrect trigger expression. Check expression part starting from "eventlog[Applications,,,,<5002>,,].last(,86400)}=0". 
[trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHuoy.png)

every day should be check event id: 5002,5004,5007. if this event id dont have is ok

Answer (score 0):

The expression is missing the host reference. The general Zabbix trigger expression/item reference syntax is:

```
{host:item.function(param)}
```

What you have is more like:

```
item.function(param)}
```

Additionally, consider using the trigger configuration helper, the "Add" button next to the expression field. It will allow to select the item and will build the basic expression for you - you can then update the function, its parameters and other values.

Additionally, your trigger function is wrong. Consider using `str()`, `count()` or a similar function - please familiarise yourself with the [available Zabbix trigger functions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions).